# "It didn't help us any", is this common?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> It didn't help us any.

I came across this usage of "any" which I don't think I have heard before.
The only case of "any" used at the end of a sentence that I am familiar with is when what comes after it is omitted and understood from the context, as in:

> Do you have friends?
> I don't have any.

However, I don't think "didn't help us any" is a similar case since it seems to be another way of saying: It didn't help us **at all**.

Is this usage of "any" common?
Are there certain verbs usually used in this construction?

Comment: Mainly US casual.

Comment: Actually, I don't think this usage is ***at all*** common. The *specific* cited example does occur in informal conversational contexts (more often in AmE rather than BrE), but apart from contexts involving negated ***help***, I can't think of any other places where it occurs. You can't normally say things like ***I didn't like him any***, for example (or if you ***do***, it'll probably be taken as a sure-fire indicator of poor schooling). The "valid" phrasing is ***any = in any way*** (that's ***not*** particularly informal / dialectal).

Comment: Yes, it is usual in the States. To be of any help. to not help any. Slightly trashy.

Answer (score 2):

This usage of **any** isn't uncommon and makes perfect sense. **Any** in this sense is used adverbially and means:

> to any degree or extent; at all

Thus, *It didn't help us any* means *It didn't help us at all.*

But in your other example, **any** is used adjectivally (and not adverbially!)

> Do you have any friends?

> i don't have any [friends.]

Here *friends* is the implied object, which is omitted.

Answer (score -1):

I personally would classify the cited usage as substandard / dialectal, on a par with *I don't feel **any too** good*.

Offhand I couldn't think of any *other* verbs apart from *[negated] **help*** that would be likely to accept adverbial modification using just ***any*** rather than the full form ***in any way***. but I did find this definition and examples in [thefreedictionary....](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/any)

> **any** defn 3. (esp US) (= **at all**)
> *It doesn't help us any.*
> *Does she sing any?*

They don't actually say it's substandard, but that's my firm belief. And I have to say that whereas I've heard the first example often enough to *tolerate* (and feasibly even *replicate*) it, the second example (with a different verb) strikes me as far more "downmarket" - and I really couldn't endorse using it in contexts like *I don't work any*, so I'd advise learners to simply avoid it completely

Comment: I disagree: "any" is a common casual substitute for "at all" in my "dialect" (midwestern Am.E). Dialectal, maybe. Substandard, degraded, or on par with your "any too good" example, not at all. Your advice for learners to avoid using it is probably good, though.

Comment: Presumably even you wouldn't be comfortable with me asking *Do you endorse this syntax any?* And since there's no obvious way to define some "line in the sand" beyond which this usage can be extended, it seems to me learners are simply asking for trouble trying to incorporate something like this into their "productive" vocabulary. (But I'm getting kinda used to being downvoted for offering that advice here! :)